# Get the geo-coordinates of a point from a pixel

Tags: python, gdal, affine-transformation

I need to get the geo-coordinates of a point from a pixel GeoTiff.
I am using the following code:

```
import gdal
from affine import Affine

# open the dataset and get the geo transform matrix
ds = gdal.Open('nodata_colored_0.681183_20190602_polygon_id_22_company_id_1.tif') 
xoffset, px_w, rot1, yoffset, px_h, rot2 = ds.GetGeoTransform()
x = 28
y = 145
# supposing x and y are your pixel coordinate this 
# is how to get the coordinate in space.
posX = px_w * x + rot1 * y + xoffset
posY = rot2 * x + px_h * y + yoffset

# shift to the center of the pixel
posX += px_w / 2.0
posY += px_h / 2.0
print(posX, posY)
```

But with different x and y i get the same result.
4810866.465768345 6559394.353978762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from osgeo import gdal
my_file = "/vsicurl/https://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/usgs/f41078a1.tif"
g = gdal.Open(my_file) # Open file
geot = g.GetGeoTransform() # Get geotransform
# Loop over pixel locations (line/column)
for l,c in [[0,0], [9921,0], [9921,6248], [0, 6249]]:
    # Do matrix multiplication without the grief of remembering
    # where things go.
    pos_x, pos_y = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(geot, l, c)
    print(l, c, pos_x, pos_y)
```

which should result in this:

```
0 0 664354.282709 4601368.606715
9921 0 765151.642709 4601368.606715
9921 6248 765151.642709 4537888.9267150005
0 6249 664354.282709 4537878.766715
```

which I think is broadly right (you may want to apply the half pixel correction to these numbers).

To do this backwards (from coords to pixels) and test the above:

```py
g = gdal.Open(my_file)
# Invert the geotransform matrix
inv_geot = gdal.InvGeoTransform(g.GetGeoTransform())
locs = [[664354.282709, 4601368.606715],
        [765151.642709, 4601368.606715],
        [765151.642709, 4537888.926715],
        [664354.282709, 4537878.766715]]
for l,c in locs:
    pos_x, pos_y = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(inv_geot, l, c)
    print(l, c, pos_x, pos_y)
```

```
664354.282709 4601368.606715 -7.275957614183426e-12 5.820766091346741e-11
765151.642709 4601368.606715 9920.999999999985 5.820766091346741e-11
765151.642709 4537888.926715 9920.999999999985 6248.000000000116
664354.282709 4537878.766715 -7.275957614183426e-12 6249.000000000058
```

Comment: Thanks, everything works. And also, tell a beginner how to convert this coordinate format to degrees, minutes and seconds

Answer (score 2):

Build an Affine transform object from GDAL like this:

```
from affine import Affine
from osgeo import gdal

# Get a GeoTransform
fname = "/vsicurl/https://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/usgs/f41078a1.tif"
ds = gdal.Open(fname)
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()  # (664354.282709, 10.16, 0.0, 4601368.606715, 0.0, -10.16)
ds = None

# Affine transform to the upper-left cell corner
T0 = Affine.from_gdal(*gt)
# Affine(10.16, 0.0, 664354.282709,
#        0.0, -10.16, 4601368.606715)

# Make cell-centered by transforming by 0.5 in each dimension
Tc = T0 * Affine.translation(0.5, 0.5)
# Affine(10.16, 0.0, 664359.362709,
#        0.0, -10.16, 4601363.526715)

# Here's a handy function to help with conversions
def rowcol2xy(r, c):
    """Returns x and y coordinate from raster row and column."""
    return Tc * (c, r)

print(rowcol2xy(145, 28))  # (664643.842709, 4599890.326715)
```

And if you need to convert from coordinates back to pixels, use the inverse to the original affine transform with the `floor` function:

```
from math import floor

# inverse matrix
Ti = ~T0
# Affine(0.0984251968503937, 0.0, -65389.20105403544,
#        0.0, -0.0984251968503937, 452890.6108971457)

cf, rf = Ti * (664643.842709, 4599890.326715)  # (28.5, 145.5)
c = floor(cf)
r = floor(rf)
r, c  # (145, 28)
```

Comment: Thanks, everything works. And also, tell a beginner how to convert this coordinate format to degrees, minutes and seconds

Answer (score 1):

`rasterio` will do the math for you with the `transform.xy` method. All you need for reference is the [affine transformation](https://www.perrygeo.com/python-affine-transforms.html) of the raster.

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.transform

tif_file = './m_3210705_sw_13_060_20200518.tif'

with rasterio.open(tif_file) as src:
    raster_transform = src.transform

pixel_x = 250
pixel_y = 500


x,y = rasterio.transform.xy(transform = raster_transform, 
                            rows = pixel_y, 
                            cols = pixel_x)

print((x,y))
(266052.3, 3647033.7)
```

For converting from coordinates to pixel row,col use the [`transform.rowcol` method](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html#rasterio.transform.rowcol).

Comment: Thanks, everything works. And also, tell a beginner how to convert this coordinate format to degrees, minutes and seconds

Comment: There are some answers to that here https://stackoverflow.com/q/2579535